# Android app has been removed from google play cause non-compete policy

Tags: android, google-play

I received an email from google yesterday said that my app has been removed from google play store.This is email's content:

> REASON FOR REMOVAL: Violation of the non-compete provision of the Developer Distribution Agreement.
>
> All violations are tracked. Serious or repeated violations of any
>   nature will result in the termination of your developer account, and
>   investigation and possible termination of related Google accounts. If
>   your account is terminated, payments will cease and Google may recover
>   the proceeds of any past sales and the cost of any associated fees
>   (such as chargebacks and payment transaction fees) from you.

Because my app is an app store, contain apps include some app from google play and some app from diferent source.
Have you ever had this problem and how i could reactive it.

Thanks !

Comment: From [Google Play Developer Distribution Agreement](https://play.google.com/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html), *"4.5 **Non-Compete**. You may not use the Market to distribute or make available any Product whose primary purpose is to facilitate the distribution of software applications and games for use on Android devices outside of the Market."*. So I think it's better not to do that again.

Comment: Thanks Andrew T, but if i remove all apps that not in google play , could i reactive my app ?

Comment: This one, I can't really comment since I never have this experience. One thing that I found is, you can try to remove them first, then make an appeal to Google by replying the email. Anyway, this question is actually off-topic since it isn't about programming, but about Google Play Store (not Google Play framework).